# Does the size of the AWS Lambda Layer affect my Lambda machine's uptime or Cold Start?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

AWS Lambda Runtime: Python 3.7

The Lambda Layer attached to my Lambda has a capacity of nearly 200MB when decompressed.

I would like to know if this large capacity Lambda Layer will affect the uptime or cold start of Lambda machine.

Comment: It depends on where you lambda is hosted, if it is hosted within VPC it would affect the uptime. I dont think it should if it is outside VPC. Refer this for more information https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/tracking-the-state-of-lambda-functions/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! The package size (including the layer) does affect the `Init Duration` "cold-start" time

This is some benchmarking test on nodejs function with our without webpack (its a tool that helps to reduce the package size for nodejs). And we can see clearly how its effect the cold start init time:
[image]

The picture was taken from our blog in lumigo:
https://lumigo.io/blog/this-is-all-you-need-to-know-about-lambda-cold-starts/
we have a detailed blog post about that issue, with solutions suggestion

Answer (score -3):

Short answers: likely not, and not really.

1. On the lifetime (uptime) of Lambda instances of different memory sizes, I happened to run some experiments recently, https://xebia.com/blog/til-that-aws-lambda-terminates-instances-preemptively/. Bottom line: I could not find a correlation between instance size and lifetime, *"Instances of 1024 MB had a comparable lifetime as instances of 256 MB, 512 MB, 1024 MB, and 2048 MB."*
2. On the effect of instance size on the cold-start duration, Mikhail Shilkov posted some analysis, https://mikhail.io/serverless/coldstarts/aws/. Bottom line: *"Most language runtimes have no visible difference in cold start duration of different instance sizes."*

Comment: Before downvoting (without giving an explanation for that), please consider that this answer addresses the original question "Does the size of the AWS Lambda Layer affect my Lambda machine's uptime or Cold Start?" directly: likely not, and not really... and additionally explains those two parts.